# "Cannot find symbol" error on scan.next

Tags: java

1. Hello! I am making an input test program in java to test out input for some future projects I have been working on. It keeps giving me an error saying "Cannot find symbol" on the scan.next in my file. Here is the code.

   ```
   import java.util.Scanner;

   class inputtest{
       public void code(){
           Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.println("Press a number");
           String key = scan.next();
           System.out.println( key );
       }
   }
   ```
2. Here is the error message:

   ```
   source_file.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
           String key = scan.next();
                        ^
     symbol:   variable scan
     location: class inputtest
   1 error
   ```

Comment: What is `scan`? Did you mean `input`?

Comment: "_Cannot find symbol on the scan.next_" Well, where did you create a variable named `scan`? Just like the compiler, I cannot find it.

Comment: and this is why I shouldn't have tried to copy what I'm seeing in the post on the computer directly to my phone P.S. The lessons I took didn't even touch on the subject of input :P

Answer (score 1):

Your `Scanner` object is named input. When you call:

```
scan.next();
```

it should be changed to:

```
input.next();
```

As you have not created a `Scanner` object under the name "input", so the compiler cannot "Find that symbol".

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because of **scan** is not declared anywhere in your code, you taking input by

`scan.next();`

where object of `Scanner` is **input** like below,

`Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);`

it should be changed to

**`Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);`**